# mysql: unrecognized service

Tags: mariadb, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I followed the instruction [here](https://downloads.mariadb.org/mariadb/repositories/#mirror=rise&distro=Ubuntu&distro_release=xenial--ubuntu_xenial&version=10.4) to install mariadb on WSL after following the steps. and I run this

`sudo service mysql start`

I got

`mysql: unrecognized service`

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Perhaps it should be `mysqld`, not `mysql`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's just a simple problem as you see but it takes me 24 hours to diagnose the problem.

Solution:
I uninstall mariadb with this command

`sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove mariadb-server`

and install `sudo apt install mysql-server` instead but it leads to a more problems

Successfully install mysql but can't start

```
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          
Errors were encountered while processing:
mysql-server-5.7
mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

so by removing mariadb's deb sources and purging mysql-common and then reinstalling it.

do:
`sudo apt edit-sources`

and look for anything containing mariadb like: `deb [arch=amd64,arm64,ppc64el] http://ftp.nluug.nl/db/mariadb/repo/10.3/ubuntu bionic main`

comment it out by putting a `#` in front of it. then run

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt purge mysql-common
sudo apt install mysql-common
```

after that you can installed mysql-server properly via sudo apt install mysql-server, then do:

```
sudo apt purge mysql-server mysql-server-5.7
sudo apt purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common mysql-server-core-5.7 mysql-client-core-5.7


sudo rm -rfv /etc/mysql /var/lib/mysql

sudo apt autoremove

sudo apt autoclean
```

Finally:

```
sudo apt update    
sudo apt install mysql-server mysql-client --fix-broken --fix-missing
```

References:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/980314/cannot-install-mysql-server-in-ubuntu16-0-4
https://askubuntu.com/questions/763534/cannot-reinstall-mysql-server-after-its-purge

Comment: Simply running the final steps resolved it for me "sudo apt update

sudo apt install mysql-server mysql-client --fix-broken --fix-missing"

Answer (score 5):

Which Linux distribution are you using on your WSL?

First, try the following:

`systemctl {start|stop|restart|status} mysql`

**OR**

`service mysql {start|stop|restart|status}`

to manage the MySQL service.

The reasons can be the following:

1. **Wrong service name**:

   On some Linux distributions, the service is named as `mysqld` instead of `mysql`.

   ***To check:*** Run `chkconfig --list` on your WSL and identify the correct service name.
2. **File permission issues**:

   Please ensure that the files in `/var/lib/mysql` have `770` permissions and ownership set to `mysql` user.

   ***To fix:***

   ```
   chmod -R 770 /var/lib/mysql
   chgrp -R mysql /var/lib/mysql
   ```

   In addition to that, ensure that the `/etc/rc.d/init.d/mysqld` script has executable permissions to modify mysqld.

   ***To fix:***

   ```
   chmod 755 /etc/rc.d/init.d/mysqld
   ```
3. **Missing/Corrupted MySQL server package**:

   Reinstall MySQL!

Comment: Okay. Can you please check with the above solutions.

Comment: chkconfig is unrecognized

Comment: I think Ubuntu recently removed `chkconfig`. You can try `sysv-rc-conf`. `sudo apt install sysv-rc-conf` Then you can use `sysv-rc-conf --list`

Comment: Unable to locate package sysv-rc-conf

Comment: Can you try using the following:
`systemctl {start|stop|restart|status} mysql`
OR
`service mysql {start|stop|restart|status}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196334/discussion-between-akshay-anurag-and-fil).